# Hyperparameter estimation of a Gaussian process when the total length of observation is less than the correlation length?

Tags: correlation, gaussian-process, rbf-kernel

If a Gaussian process has a kernel covariance function that is parametrized by a correlation length-like parameter (Like in RBF of an SM kernel), to estimate the hyperparameters, it is common knowledge that at least the total time of observation should be enough to contain the low correlation regions (like till $4l$ or more). However, is it possible to estimate the length parameter when the observation interval is less than one length scale (correlation length $< l$)?